# how to add a vertical scrollbar to checkbox in python tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar

I read the input for checkbox from a text file and this has increased more than the given window size.
How to add a scrollbar to this to view all the contents of the checkbox.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: added the code.

```
from tkinter import *
import os


error = []
window = ""
with open("op.txt") as inp:
    for lines in inp:
        if lines.strip() == "done":
            error.append(window)
            window = ""
        else:
            window += lines

print(len(error))

root = Tk()
root.minsize(500, 500)
cbTexts={}
cbVariables={}
cb={}
for i in error:
    cbTexts[i] = StringVar()
    cbTexts[i].set(i)
    cbVariables[i] = IntVar()
    cbVariables[i].set(0)
    cb[i] = Checkbutton(root, textvariable=cbTexts[i], variable=cbVariables[i])
    cb[i].pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post ur code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ScrolledText`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html) to hold the checkbuttons.

Below is an simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = tk.Tk()

text = ScrolledText(root, width=20, height=10)
text.pack()

for i in range(30):
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(text, text=(i+1), bg='white', anchor='w')
    text.window_create('end', window=cb)
    text.insert('end', '\n')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Also if you don't want to delete any checkbutton by mistake then change the `text['state'] = 'disabled'` after adding all the checkbuttons.